# Terminal: Remove specific extension recursively

Tags: terminal, folders, macos

I have a folder, containing many other folders.

Some of the folders contained therein (at arbitrary depths) have a specific extension, let's say, `.ext`:

```
TopFolder
+ Folder1
| + Folder11.ext
|   +Folder111
+ Folder2.ext
```

I want to use Terminal to remove that extension from all folders in any subfolder so that it looks like this:

```
TopFolder
+ Folder1
| + Folder11
|   +Folder111
+ Folder2
```

I've played around with find and xargs, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ find TopFolder -print
Topfolder
Topfolder/Folder1
Topfolder/Folder1/Folder11.ext
Topfolder/Folder1/Folder11.ext/Folder111
Topfolder/Folder2.ext
$ find TopFolder -name '*.ext' -print | while read i; do mv -v "$i" "${i%.ext}";done
$ find TopFolder
TopFolder
TopFolder/Folder1
TopFolder/Folder1/Folder11
TopFolder/Folder1/Folder11/Folder111
TopFolder/Folder2
```

The first and last find are just to show the before and after hierarchy. Here's how the middle find, the one that does the actual work, works:

```
$ find TopFolder -name '*.ext' -print
```

This finds everything in TopFolder matching the pattern `'*.ext'`, that is all files and directories ending in .ext, and prints the path to each. If you want to limit it to just directories, add `-type d`.

```
while read i; do
```

`read i` reads from standard input into the shell variable `i`. `while` loops until `read i` returns false, which it does on end-of-file. Being `find`'s output is being piped to the while, `read`'s standard input is the output of the `find`, so `read` will read a line at a time from the `find` output until there's none left.

```
mv -v "$i" "${i%.ext}"
```

This does the actual rename. The `-v` is in there just so you can see what's happening, you can leave it out if you want. `"$i"` is the source, quoted in case any element of the path in `$i` contains spaces. `"${i%.ext}"` is the destination, which is `$i`, with any trailing `.ext` removed.

```
done
```

This just terminates the while loop.

Note that this is in bash, it should be doable in other fairly modern shells, but the syntax may be a bit different.

Comment: Wonderful answer and great explanation; thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a find inline script and parameter expansion.

```
find . -type d -name '*.ext' -exec ksh -c 'for dir
    do mv "$dir" "${dir%.*}"
    done' _ {} +
```

Comment: This did not work for me.